# Merging two neighboring cells in grid of type SpatialPolygonsDataFrame?

Tags: r, merge, vector-grid

I have a grid of type `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` (each cell has a set of data attributes). I want to merge each cell which has a surface < X with one of its neighbours. An example is depicted in the picture.

[image]

I loop over all cells and see which one has to be merged, then I get its neighbors with `gTouches`, but I couldn't get it work with functions like `gUnaryUnion` and `aggregate`.

Here is my code:

```
for(ix in(1:length(mygridshp))){
   if(mygridshp@polygons[[ix]]@area < 20000){
      neighbor_cells <- gTouches(mygridspolygons[ix], my_other_cells, byid=TRUE);
      neighbor_cells_ids <- my_other_cells$unit_id[neighbor_cells == TRUE];
      if(length(neighbor_cells_ids) > 0){
          first_neighbor <- mygridshp[mygridshp@data$unit_id==neighbor_cells_ids[1],];
          new_cell <- aggregate(rbind(first_neighbor, mygridshp[ix,]));
          new_cell <- gUnaryUnion(spgeom=union(first_neighbor,mygridshp[ix,]));
      }
   }
}
```

Any better idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a code that can do this. It's a little bit complicated but it works !

```
##### function #####
      get_my_first_father <- function(x){
         if(list_of_my_father[x] == x){ return (x); }
         else{ return (get_my_first_father(list_of_my_father[x])); }
      }
      #####
      # for each cell, we look for other cells who are supposed to merge with it (children)
      list_of_my_children <- vector("list", length(mygridspolygons));
      list_of_my_father <- seq.int(length(mygridspolygons));
      for(ix in(1:length(mygridspolygons))){                    
      #for each cell smaller than X, we merge it to its neighbor of the same district
      if(mygridshp@polygons[[ix]]@area < grid_cell_min_area){
         my_district <- mygridshp@data[ix,'dist_code'];
         # all cells of my district
         my_district_cells <- mygridshp[mygridshp@data$dist_code == my_district,];
         # who are my neighbors
         neighbor_cells <- gTouches(mygridspolygons[ix], my_district_cells, byid=TRUE);
         my_district_cells@data$is_neighbor = as.vector(neighbor_cells);
         # my neighbors cells
         my_neighbor_cells <- my_district_cells[my_district_cells@data$is_neighbor == TRUE,];
         # who are not already my children
         my_neighbor_cells <- my_neighbor_cells[!my_neighbor_cells$unit_id %in% 
         unlist(lapply(list_of_my_children[[ix]], function(e) e$unit_id)),];
         # for each cell we calculate the length of the boundaries
         if(length(my_neighbor_cells) > 0){
            line_length <- 0;
            for(lx in(1:length(my_neighbor_cells))){
               my_line <- rgeos::gIntersection(mygridshp[ix,], my_neighbor_cells[lx,], byid = TRUE);
               if(class(my_line) == 'SpatialLines'){
                  new_line_length <- SpatialLinesLengths(my_line);
                  if(new_line_length > line_length){
                     selected_neighbor <- my_neighbor_cells[lx,];
                     line_length <- new_line_length;
                  }
               }
            }
            # getting the big father
            my_father <- get_my_first_father(selected_neighbor$unit_id);
            list_of_my_father[ix] <- my_father;
            list_of_my_children[[my_father]] <- c(list_of_my_children[[my_father]], mygridshp[ix,]);
            # if I have children, they also goes to my father
            if(length(list_of_my_children[[mygridshp[ix,]$unit_id]]) > 0){
               list_of_my_children[[my_father]] <- c(list_of_my_children[[my_father]], list_of_my_children[[mygridshp[ix,]$unit_id]]);
               list_of_my_children[mygridshp[ix,]$unit_id] <- list(NULL);
            }
         }                  
      }
   }


# merge spatial polygons
   my_new_grid <- mygridshp[1,]; # to avoid raster::bind NULL issue
   for(ix in(1:length(list_of_my_children))){
      if(length(list_of_my_children[[ix]]) > 0){
         new_polysp <- as(mygridshp[ix,], 'SpatialPolygons');
         for(lx in(1:length(list_of_my_children[[ix]]))){
            new_polysp <- gUnaryUnion(spgeom=union(new_polysp,list_of_my_children[[ix]][[lx]]));
         }
         new_polyspdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(new_polysp, mygridshp[ix,]@data, match.ID=FALSE);
         my_new_grid <- raster::bind(my_new_grid, new_polyspdf);    
      }
      else if(mygridshp@polygons[[ix]]@area >= grid_cell_min_area){
         my_new_grid <- raster::bind(my_new_grid, mygridshp[ix,]);
      }
   }
```